# making correct pagination

Tags: php, pagination, config, codeigniter-3

When I display a data table for this page it works, but when I try to add pagination it becomes an error. And even if I have a similar problem where do I find a solution

How to make the correct script to display pagination based table data?

Where is the error in my code?

**View**

```
<table class="table mt-3">
        <thead class="table-danger text-center">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Kode</th>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Nama Barang</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-center table-primary">

            <?php foreach ( $barang as $tb ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-uppercase"><a href="" class="text-dark text-decoration-none"><?= $tb['barang_kode'] ?></a></td>
                    <td class="text-capitalize"><a href="" class="text-dark text-decoration-none"><?= $tb['type_nama'] ?></a></td>
                    <td class="text-capitalize"><a href="" class="text-dark text-decoration-none"><?= $tb['barang_nama'] ?></a></td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn  btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url(); ?>gudang/hapus_type/<?= $tb['barang_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Yakin akan menghapus data ini ?');">Hapus</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= base_url(); ?>gudang/ubah_type/<?= $tb['barang_id']; ?>">Ubah</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="container">
          <?php  // Tampilkan link-link paginationnya
          echo $barang['pagination'];  ?>
    </div>
```

**models**

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('gudang/lihat_type');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->query($query)->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;

        $config['full_tag_open']   = '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-t-xs m-b-xs">';
        $config['full_tag_close']  = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link']      = 'First';
        $config['first_tag_open']  = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_link']       = 'Last';
        $config['last_tag_open']   = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close']  = '</li>';
        $config['next_link']       = ' <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i> ';
        $config['next_tag_open']   = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close']  = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link']       = ' <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></i> ';
        $config['prev_tag_open']   = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close']  = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open']    = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close']   = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open']    = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close']   = '</li>';        // End style pagination 
        $this->pagination->initialize($config); // Set konfigurasi paginationnya
        $page = ($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment'])) ? $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']) : 0;
        $query .= " LIMIT ".$page.", ".$config['per_page'];
        $data['limit'] = $config['per_page'];
        $data['total_rows'] = $config['total_rows'];
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links(); 
        $data['barang'] = $this->db->query($query)->result_array(); 
        return $data
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Haem error  File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/karyatohaputra/application/models/Gudang_model.php
Line: 149
Function: query

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/karyatohaputra/application/controllers/Gudang.php
Line: 126
Function: getRelasi

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/karyatohaputra/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: You should [edit] the error message to your question.

Comment: @YusufReza why are you add pagination in the model, not in the controller? also, that error contain no message, which is useless, could you provide the error message?

Comment: `echo $barang['pagination'];` this is wrong.
use Only `$pagination` to show links

Answer (score 0):

On the **model**, change :

```
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

to

```
$data['barang']['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

so that the pagination data is moved inside the `$barang` array.

Comment: error :  File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/karyatohaputra/application/models/Gudang_model.php
Line: 149
Function: query

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/karyatohaputra/application/controllers/Gudang.php
Line: 126
Function: getRelasi

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/karyatohaputra/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: could you show the controller that calling the model?

Comment: public function lihat_type()
 {
  $data['judul'] = 'Daftar Type Barang';
  $data ['barang'] = $this->Gudang_model->getRelasi();
  if($this->input->post('keyword'))
  {
   $data['barang'] = $this->Gudang_model->cariTypeBarang();
  }
  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('gudang/lihat_type', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }